# List of specific day/days in a given date range

Tags: sql-server

I was looking for List of specific day/days in a given date range and i found this

```
declare @d datetime
select @d = '20100101'  --'20090101'  if you want 2009 etc etc

select dateadd(dd,number,@d) from master..spt_values
where type = 'p'
and year(dateadd(dd,number,@d))=year(@d)
and DATEPART(dw,dateadd(dd,number,@d)) = 7
```

at
  [get date of all saturdays in a given year - sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839923/get-date-of-all-saturdays-in-a-given-year-sql-server)

I was wondering if I can use start date and end date instead of year, and can get list of two days like Saturday and Sunday.

regards

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the number of day for each days between @start and @end:

```
declare @start date = '20151001', @end date = '20151017'
Select c = DATEDIFF(DAY, @start, @end)/ 7
     + case when (7 + DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @start) + (DATEDIFF(DAY, @start, @end)% 7) - d) % 7 <= (DATEDIFF(DAY, @start, @end)%7) then 1 else 0 end
From (values(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7)) as days(d)
```

Output:

```
Day 1   2
Day 2   2
Day 3   2
Day 4   2
Day 5   3
Day 6   3
Day 7   3
```

It completly avoid using recursive CTE and DATEADD on each day betwen @start and @end. This is just some math.

For multiple dates, you could also use something like this altough it is not as efficient on big ranges:

```
declare @start date = '20151001', @end date = '20151017'

Select DATEADD(DAY, n, @start), DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, n, @start))
From (
    Select top(DATEDIFF(DAY, @start, @end)+1) ROW_NUMBER() over(order by n)-1
    From (
        Select 1 From (values(1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) as v1(n)
        Cross Join (values(1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) as v2(n)
        Cross Join (values(1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) as v3(n)
    ) as v(n)
) as o(n)
Where DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, n, @start)) in (7, 1)
```

Output:

```
DATE        WEEKDAY
2015-10-03  7
2015-10-04  1
2015-10-10  7
2015-10-11  1
2015-10-17  7
```

Here, 7 = Saturday, 1 = Sunday. You can add any value between 1 and 7 or it could come from another table.
It could be replaced by Day Names if you use DATENAME.

You then only have to add a group by and/or a sum to get the number of Saturdays and Sundays.

V1/V2/V3 avoid using a recursive query and quickly generate a list of number from 0 to X (and up to 999). X is the difference between @start and @end in days. Add v4 if you need a 10.000 days range (and so on...) but 1000 is enough for over 2 years, almost 3.

Answer (score 0):

Recursively select all dates `from_date` to `To_Date` and then use `DATEPART` to check whether it's a Weekend or Not.

```
declare @from_date as date---your from date
declare @to_date as date---your to date

;WITH dates AS (
    SELECT CONVERT( DATE, @from_date) AS a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD( DAY, 1, a )
    FROM   dates
    WHERE  DATEADD( DAY, 1, a ) <= @to_date --including the @to_date
)
SELECT a
FROM   dates
WHERE  DATEPART( dw, a ) IN ( 1, 7 ) --- Saturday Or Sunday
```

If you want to check Only Sunday

```
SELECT a
    FROM   dates
    WHERE  DATEPART( dw, a )=1
```

If you want to check Only Saturday

```
SELECT a
    FROM   dates
    WHERE  DATEPART( dw, a )=7
```

Answer (score -1):

A small modification for rajeshmpanchal scrpit.

1. Add for cte maxrecursion - default 100 rows.
2. set datefirst 1 /* monday *

You can try this:

```
set datefirst 1 /* monday */

declare @v_date_start datetime
declare @v_date_stop datetime

set @v_date_start = '2015-05-01'
set @v_date_stop = '2020-10-01' 

;with date_cte 
as
(
    select  @v_date_start [date]
    union all
    select  dateadd(day, 1, cte.date) [date]        
    from    date_cte [cte]
    where   dateadd(day, 1, cte.date) <= @v_date_stop 

)

select  cte.date
    ,   datename(dw, cte.date) [day_name]
from    date_cte [cte]
where   datepart(dw, cte.date) in (6,7)
option  (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. problem solved. regards and respect.